# Automatically add ssh keys to ssh agent on Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh

I want to access GitHub via SSH. I have created a passphrase protected SSH key which I want to add to the ssh-agent on login.

If I add a SSH key to ssh-agent via command `ssh-add ~/path/to/key </dev/null` and have ssh-askpass client like ksshaskpass installed on the system then it would ask for the password. On KDE, this password is also persisted across login.

How can I automatically add ssh keys to the ssh agent on startup in Raspberry Pi? On regular Linux, I have ksshaskpass add the keys to the ssh-agent via a command like `ssh-add ~/path/to/key </dev/null`. The ssh-askpass available in Pi can ask for the ssh passphrase but it can't remember it.

How can I save ssh key phassphrase and it be provided automatically to ssh-agent like ksshaskpass?

Comment: does https://superuser.com/questions/1360324/gpg-remove-passphrase answer your question? Remembering a passphrase defeats the purpose of a key protected by one.  As such if you want to just use the key file, remove the passphrase.

Comment: It may help you get a good answer if you could explain what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Seamus I want to add my ssh key to the ssh-agent so that I can commit to GitHub via SSH https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: @Abel I am talking about SSH key and not GPG key.

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger: Perhaps the issue is actually that you chose password protection, when that's not what you wanted?? AFAIK, when you choose to protect your keys with a password, you are stuck with always providing a password. In any event, I don't think there is anything unique about RPi's implementation and configuration of SSH keys and `ssh-agent` -- which means that your question is considered ["Off Topic" under the rules here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: i think you need to read up on what Asymmetric Key Encryption is.  Maybe also read up on what gpg and an "ssh key" are.  You can also just generate a new key without the additional password and replace your old ones.

Comment: @seamus Ksshaskpass stores password in the kwallet which is unlocked with the user password. I was wondering if there is something like that for Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger: I fervently hope that there is nothing like that in RPi OS. By way of explanation for that comment: I personally feel that many of the ideas that try to make computer technology *"more accessible"* fail to do so. Maybe [learn to use](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-2) the "native" tools - they aren't that difficult.

Comment: @Seamus the link that you have provided asks to set up a passphrase in step 3 which is exactly what I have done which is the exact problem here. Every time I add the ssh key to the ssh-agent it would ask me for the ssh key's passphrase. This passphrase is saved to `kwallet` by `ksshaskpass`. I feel like I am not able to explain the functionality. Adjectives in your sentences make me think you are more into prooving something including that the question itself is wrong.

Comment: @SudhirSinghKhanger: RE `"proving...the question itself is wrong"`... No, not at all. I'm simply of the *opinion* that these apps are not particularly useful because I feel they add complexity instead of manage it. However, 2 things: **1)** `ksshaskpass` ***is*** in the RPi repo (per `apt-cache search ksshaskpass`), and can be installed simply w/ `apt`  **2)** I do wonder if your question might fare better on another SE site as it does not seem to concern something that is **specific** to the RPi.

Comment: @Seamus `ksshaskpass` is KDE desktop which means if I pull it in on RPi LXDE desktop then effectively it will pull in all or a huge number of KDE packages. 1) I am trying to figure out a solution which can work in RPi LXDE. But it seems like using SSH key with no passphrase seems to be the best option. I am not a security expert so not sure if that is secure.

Comment: @Seamus I think I have found a perfect solution for this problem. It turns out my password manager can also add SSH agent. If and when I am asked for a ssh key then the password manager can be used for it. There seems to be another option which I might have to explore `keychain`. Thanks for taking time to help me out with this.

Comment: Congratulations! You should answer your own question. It may help others, and you can `select` it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [the comments](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135971/automatically-add-ssh-keys-to-ssh-agent-on-raspberry-pi#comment231315_135971), the OP says:

> It turns out my password manager can also add SSH agent. If and when I am asked for a ssh key then the password manager can be used for it. There seems to be another option which I might have to explore `keychain`.